# Десериализировать объект json в модель и поместить данные в БД

Tags: c#, mysql, json

У меня есть данные в json:

```
{                  
    "ProjectId": 4,
    "Date": "20/08/2015",
    "TaskDescription": "this is the description",
    "TimeWorked": 3,
    "Note": "This is the note"
}
```

Мне нужно десериализировать json в такую модель:

```
public class TimesheetListModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public decimal TimeWorked { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

И закинуть эту модель в таблицу базы с соответствующими полями.

Я пока что написал только это:

```
public bool SaveTask(JObject task)
{
    TimesheetListModel newTask = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimesheetListModel>((string) task);
    /* здесь должен быть код который все это делает */
    return true;
}
```

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Можно дальше преобразовать в XML и забросить на скл сервер. Так как поддержка JSON type будет только в 2016 скл сервере.

Comment: @cpp_user поддержка сериализации со стороны БД вообще не требуется в данном вопросе.

Comment: Но избавляет от не нужной работы по маппингу XML в SQL таблицу.

Comment: Какая технология доступа к БД используется: ADO.NET или какая-нибудь ORM?